# Broken image link on the new Stack Exchange blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, broken-link

Before I jump on to the problem, let me first congratulate [Jon Chan](http://blog.stackexchange.com/authors/jonhmchan) and his team for the newly re-designed Stack Exchange blog. I like it very much, great job!

While searching on Google, I stumbled upon [Customizing stackexchange.com](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/customizing-stackexchange-com/) blog post of Jeff Atwood and found few broken images. There are currently four images are broken on this post, Here is one of them:

> [image]

Upon doing an *inspect element* on one of the broken image (*same goes for all other broken images on the post*), I found out that it is currently pointing to:

`https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackexchange-genuine-example11.png`

The newly re-designed Stack Exchange blog is now moved to a new location: http://blog.stackexchange.com and the old blog URL i.e. https://blog.stackoverflow.com has the correct mapping of URL redirection (also called URL forwarding) and works perfectly.

But, the problem lies in the latter part i.e. `/wp-content/uploads/` directory structure does not exist anymore at the new blog location. I read the Jon Chan's [How We Built Our Blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/) post (*nice writeup! btw*) where he talks about his custom Python script. Here is the relevant excerpt taken from that post:

> I wrote a Python script to go through all the imported posts, looked
> for references to WordPress hosted content, download all the static
> assets into **images/wordpress** in the repo, and changed all the
> links to relative paths on Jekyll. Worked surprisingly well.

In other words, all of the old `/wp-content/uploads/` static assets is now resides under the `/images/wordpress/` directory at the new blog location. So, Jon's find and replace script should have worked (which it did for the most of the part) as intended to be but apparently it did not catch few of them. At least on [this](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/customizing-stackexchange-com/) blog post and few other like [Welcome Valued Associate Nick Craver](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/welcome-valued-associate-nick-craver/), [Logo Design Contest](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest/) or [Stack Overflow Beta Design](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-beta-design/). We could possibly have more but these are the ones I have found so far.

I believe it's a minor bug somewhere in the script and could be fixed with few lines of code tweaking. Also, the static content link mapping problem would not have occurred at all if the directory name was unchanged as the URL redirection (as stated above) would have taken care of it. But, there must a reason for this change.

Upon investigating further, I found out that the issue with broken images does not end here. They will still appear as broken even if Jon's script replaces the path to the correct one. Because the images have not been uploaded (or copied) to the blog's new `/images/wordpress/` directory at all. They are missing!

For example, try clicking on the following link:

`## I replaced old dir. path /wp-content/uploads/ to the new /images/wordpress/`
https://blog.stackexchange.com/images/wordpress/stackexchange-genuine-example11.png

So, in a nutshell, in order to fix this broken images link problem, we need to make sure that not only they are pointing to new path i.e. `/images/wordpress/` but also do exists (i.e. uploaded) at the blog's new location.

Please fix this at your earliest.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for editing and adding a broken image snapshot to my post.

Comment: My pleasure, though the FHRC is even more important... :-)

Comment: Jon Chan, I think your newly re-designed blog also broke SE team members blog URL. The SE team members blog posts are now in the "authors"(as oppose to author) directory. @Jaydles please update your profile page to point the blog link to correct location at: https://blog.stackexchange.com/authors/jhanlon/

Comment: You know they can't see your comment, right? They don't have a special comment sniffer that monitor all comments around the network.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I didn't know that. Thanks. I will use the other route to notify this.

Comment: If you have new bug to report it should be done by starting a new question. What "other route" you have in mind?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I thought I would be able to get the email id as some of the SE team do post their official email address in their Profile. But, I am out of luck here. I am drafting a new question for this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, easy enough to get to Jon Chan Facebook profile but yeah, better start new bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks. I thought of that too but decided not to got that route... Anyway, I have posted a new bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260440/stack-exchange-core-team-member-blog-url-link-is-broken

Comment: This is a known issue. Like you said, the script I wrote should have captured most of the images here, but many of them weren't captured (some of these were actually missing even in the old one). I'm working to recover as many of the images as we can now, but this is something that may take some time to recover.

Comment: @JonChan Not a problem... I m glad to know that you're on top of it.

Comment: @Jon any updates, almost 3 months later? In addition to what OP showed here, [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) also contains the non exitant image http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/current-stack-exchange-2-public-betas.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard as noted in the post, we're missing some of the images and need to restore them from our backup on a case-by-case basis. I'm going to see what can get done for the posts mentioned here specifically.

Comment: @Jon thanks, better than nothing I guess - one by one, image by image.