# Author links on Stack Exchange blog are broken after switching to Jekyll

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, blog

The blog URL link on [Jay Hanlon's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles) page is broken.

It's currently pointing to: 
https://blog.stackexchange.com/author/jhanlon/

The correct blog URL address is:
https://blog.stackexchange.com/authors/jhanlon/

Looking at the two URLs above, you can see the reason for this broken link. The directory name was changed.

Team members (or blog authors in this case) at [the newly re-design Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/07/the-new-stack-exchange-blog/) are now moved to the **authors** (as opposed to *author*) directory. This problem would not have arisen at all if the directory name was not changed.

But, [Jon Chan](http://blog.stackexchange.com/authors/jonhmchan) and his team might have some valid reason for this directory name change.

Instead of posting a new bug report, I originally thought of reporting this directly to Jay via email, (as some of the SE team members do include official email address in their Profile) but, I was out of luck in this case.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  Fixed my link for now, and gave Jon (who worked on the blog) a heads up that the author/authors slug may break old links unintentionally.

Comment: @Jaydles No problem. But, for some reason I still see its pointing to broken one. What place did you fixed it? Here are the two places it still shows old ones. 1: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles (right sidebar under the SO Careers Profile) and 2: http://stackexchange.com/users/140824/jaydles?tab=accounts

Comment: I fixed the "About Me" one, but had omitted the "Website" field.  Fixed that now.  The other link is the "Network Profile" - I think that may be caching, but will follow-up.  Thanks!

Comment: @random Are all of your edit comments stand alone, or have you attempted short series with any stretch of them?

Comment: @Jaydles Thanks. I hope Jon also get to see my other bug report which relates to the broken images issue on the blog posts of SE's core team members including Jeff Atwood - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260056/broken-image-link-on-the-new-stack-exchange-blog