# Podcasts missing from new blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, podcast

The blogs *used* to have links to the old Joel & Jeff Stack Overflow podcasts. These are now all gone. Instead, there is now a sad and dismal `[display_podcast]` line at the bottom; see [podcast #41](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/02/podcast-41/) for example.

Can these be reinstated please?

To be clear, these are not the new Stack *Exchange* podcasts which were started [much later](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/04/podcast-88/) and are embedded into blog pages with a SoundCloud widget.

Comment: +1 hope it gets attention soon. In my case I found the images are missing from Jeff's blog post: [Broken image link on the new Stack Exchange blog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260056/broken-image-link-on-the-new-stack-exchange-blog)

Comment: I'll ping Matt on Monday to make sure he's seen this. Ideally, those get uploaded to SoundCloud too.

Comment: We are also tracking this as [an issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues/138) on GitHub

Comment: We definitely want to recover these. It's on our radar and a fix will come in less than six to eight weeks.

Comment: These episodes were reinstated to the blog as part of the latest round of changes.